# How to get ride of a empty page when using Doxygen to generate markdown user documentation

Tags: doxygen

Currently I am using Doxygen to generate a user document from a few markdown files.
I want to generate a custom navigation tree like the following:

- Install
- --Install on macos
- --Install on windows
- --Install on linux

And I have 4 markdown pages, here. let's say they are "install.md", "macos.md", "windows.md" and "linux.md".

My install.md file is as follow:

- @page install
- @subpage macos
- @subpage windows
- @subpage linux

and the "macos.md" , "windows.md" and "linux.md" each has its own page title:
such as @page macos , @page windows and @page linux.

The result is very good, but it generate a few empty pages with the file name.

How could I get rid of all these empty page files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for ages for a decent solution, and this is what i found:

In your main markdown file (here install.md), define a group, such as:

```
\defgroup GrpDummyPages HiddenEmpty
@{
@}
```

Then in your subpages, for intance your 'windows.md', add at the beginning:

```
\ingroup GrpDummyPages
```

In your tree view will appeaer a 'modules' section, with sub-category 'HiddenEmpty', which will contain the pages/files where you put the ingroup command.

Answer (score -1):

With doxygen 1.8.10, this seems to work: Use the Header ID Attributes {#pageId} Marker after a Headline in the .md files *exclusively*.

Doxygen doc for that:  http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_header_id

Using @page works, but it will create the additional empty page in the navigation tree.

An example... Assuming a little hierarchy:

```
Main.md
   SubPage1       (Subfolder)
   SubPage1.md    (File in Subfolder)
```

Main.md:

```
# Main Page {#mainpage}

This is text...

* \subpage SubPage1
```

SubPage1.md:

```
# First Subpage Title {#SubPage1}

Some text for the subpage
```

The hierarchy will be represented in the generated TreeView, you can nest pages as you like..

---

The following demonstrates the problem .. it will create the additional empty page ...

SubPage1.md:          (Buggy)

```
@page SubPage1  

# First Subpage Title

Some text for the subpage
```

Comment: hi. For me this also places a page in the left tree with name SubPage1.

Comment: @Napseis ... I am sorry to hear that. Did you use Doxygen 1.8.10 (latest Version at this time)?

Comment: I have Doxygen 1.8.9.1

Comment: Basically, if the page is not a @Subpage of something else, it will appear in the index.